# convert svg or ttf to otf, eot, woff

Tags: command-line, software-recommendation, web-development, font-converter

I'm looking for a command line software/script for linux/ubuntu that can help me convert `svg` or `ttf` to `otf`, `eot` and `woff` formats. 
I've tried `fontmin`,`webify`, `fontforge`, `eot-utils`, `sfnt2woff`, `ttf2woff` and other alternative as much as i can, I can't find a good converter. 
`fontmin` convert files to `ttf` `otf` but doesn't convert to `woff` and is always broken. `fontforge` doesn't convert to `woff` and `eot` either, `sfnt2woff` and `ttf2woff` only convert to `woff`.

I'm simply trying to make web fonts `css` after converting process, I've also tried many alternative for it but so far no success at all.

Please let me know if there are batter option to accomplish my requirements. and feel free to edit and correct my question.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to convert `ttf` to `eot, woff` and `svg` with Ruby:

```bsh
sudo apt install ruby
gem install convert_font
convert_font convert -i folder/font-file.ttf -f eot,woff,svg
```

Note that `convert_font` is not longer developed and outdated (as of today, december 2020, there was no update [since 7 years](https://github.com/jonlunsford/convert_font) - apparently [this fork was updated since then](https://github.com/naveed-ahmad/convert_font)), I hope you'll find a way to make it work with your setup

Comment: It seems like it has stopped working since. Also, if anybody tries this, be advised the script stops working because it tries to connect to "ofc.p.mashape.com". Might be okay, might suspicious. Maybe the gem does not do the work on the clients computer, but remotely?